# Delete entities having datetime older than N seconds from google-app-engine ndb

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am wanting to delete old entities from ndb. The entities have a ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True) property called date:

```
class Mjcode(ndb.Model):
    code = ndb.StringProperty()
    ifv = ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is how far I've come:

```
mjcode_keys = Mjcode.query().fetch(keys_only=True)
countOfMjcodes = len(mjcode_keys)
self.response.write('Mjcode - found entity count: ' + str(countOfMjcodes) + '<br/>')
if countOfMjcodes > 0:
    self.response.write('Deleting...<br/>')
    ndb.delete_multi(mjcode_keys)
else:
    self.response.write('No delete needed.<br/>')
```

This deletes the entities, but at this point it deletes all of them. What is the syntax I should enter - I suppose inside of query()? Let's say I want to purge all entities older than X number of seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [filter queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filter_by_prop) like this:

```
import datetime
earliest = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
Mjcode.query(Mjcode.date <= earliest).fetch(keys_only=True)
```

This will remove any entities older than 7 days. You can edit the [datetime.timedelta](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.1/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) to change the time after which entities are removed.